# Oracle DB, how to add seconds to TIMESTAMP and compare result with current moment

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time, timestamp

In a function, I need to add certain amount of seconds to a variable of type `TIMESTAMP(6)`, and compare if the current moment is before the result.

How do I add seconds to a `TIMESTAMP` variable and get the current time in a format, so it can be compared with the result? How do I form expression for this condition?

Amount of the seconds to be added is stored in a `INTEGER` typed variable.

Comment: systimestamp will return you the current system timestamp

Comment: What is the result here? Please provide examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to add seconds to a timestamp and to perform a check against the system time:

```
select timestamp '2017-01-20 12:00:00.000000' as value,
       timestamp '2017-01-20 12:00:00.000000' + interval '10' second as valuePlus10,
       case
         when timestamp '2017-01-20 12:00:00.000000' + interval '10' second > systimestamp then '> timestamp'
         else '< timestamp'
       end as checkVal
from dual
```

If you have the number of second to add already stored in some numeric variable, you may use something like:

```
declare
    vSeconds number := 10;
    vTimestamp1 timestamp(6);
    vTimestamp2 timestamp(6);
begin
    select vTimestamp1 + NUMTODSINTERVAL(vSeconds, 'second')
    into vTimestamp2
    from dual;
end;
```